# Retrieve variable from modulo equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I do have the following equation

$x \mod C = A-B$

where $x$ is a variable, while $A$, $B$ and $C$ are parameters. This equation seems quite simple, but I cannot find a way to solve it and get $x$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your notation is a but unconvential/confusing to me, do you mean that $x$ reduced modulo $C$ equals $A-B$ or that $x$ is congruent to $A-B$ modulo $C$, or something else entirely? If you mean either of the my first two suggestion, there is not a unique solution, but you can easily find an infintie family of solutions

Comment: Hi Noah, I apologize for the confusion, I have been always using this notation. What I mean is $x\mod C$ equals $A-B$. Alternatively, if we want to further simplify the notation, $x\mod C$ equals $D$. For example, $7\mod 2=1$. I don't know what 'reduced' means, maybe if you could explain that, I might find a more standard way to write it down. I'll add a link to try to avoid any further confusion: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7+modulo+2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's clarify the difference between the two notions I was asking about in my comment. Given integers $a,b,c$ we can ask whether $a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $c$, often denoted
$$
a \equiv b \mod c
$$
This is equivalent to saying that there exists some integer $k$ such that
$$
a-b = c\cdot k
$$
Note that I am using an equal sign here, and I used the congruence (three lines) in the previous equation.

The other notion, which you may be more familiar with especially if you're coming from a computer science background is the reduction operation, sometimes denoted with $\mathbin\%$ i.e.
$$
a\mathbin\%c = b
$$
Which we take to mean that there exists an integer $k$ such that $0 \leq a+c\cdot k < c$ and that
$$
a+ck = b
$$
These are very interrelated notions, but they are not the same. The you can think of the first idea, congruence modulo $c$ as a kind of loosening of the definition of equality and the second idea, the reduction operation as an operation on the integers. To see how they can be different, note that if $a = 2, b =5,$ and $ c =3$ then $a \equiv b \mod c$ since
$$
2 - 5 = (-1) \cdot 3
$$
However,
$$
2 \mathbin\% 3 = 2 \neq 5
$$
This is a distinction well worth understanding. Based on how you phrased your original question and how you answered my question in the comments, I take it to mean that you mean the reduction operation, i.e. you want to find solutions to
$$
(x\mathbin\%c) = a-b
$$
If $a-b<0$ or if $a-b\geq c$ then there are no solutions since $0\leq x\mathbin\%c < c$. If $0\leq a-b < c$, then you have an infinitely set of solutions namely the equation holds for any $x$ of the form $a-b + k\cdot c$ for all integer values of $k$.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: TeX note:  you may find that the spacing in $x \mathbin\% c$ `x \mathbin\% c` is better than that in $x \% c$ `x \% c`; the former treats `%` as a binary operator, whereas the latter treats it as punctuation (I think).

Comment: @LSpice thanks, that's a great tip I didn't know about (or perhaps knew at one point and have forgotten)

Comment: Hi Noah, yes, this is pretty clear now. What I meant in the original post was the reduction operation. Thanks for the detailed response.